# Impossible to scan RFID tags using libnfc, PN532, and RPi3

Tags: python, nfc, raspberry-pi3, rfid, lib-nfc

I recently bought this NFC/RFID reader [PN532 module V3](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/PN532-NFC-RFID-module-V3-NFC-with-Android-phone-extension-of-RFID-provide-Schematic-and-library/32759875474.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.LnrZJu)

[image]

I want to use it with my raspberry pi 3. I have install and configured the library [libnfc](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc). The PN532 is connected with I2C. I have well enabled it on my RPi.

My problem is that I cannot scan anything. Indeed, when I run the function `nfc-poll` in the console, I get this :

```
nfc-poll uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC reader: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1 opened
NFC device will poll during 30000 ms (20 pollings of 300 ms for 5 modulations)
nfc_initiator_poll_target: Success
```

During the poll, I passed near the PN532 a lot of different tags, even those that arrived with it. But there is never any detection. Nevertheless, the RPi seems to communicate correctly with the PN532, as is shown in the second line.

---

The command `i2cdetect -y 1` is well returning :

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- 24 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

---

The PN532 is wired as follow :

- GND --> GPIO 6
- VCC --> GPIO 4
- SDA --> GPIO 3
- SCL --> GPIO 5

I have checked the wiring (i have well the yellow led ON, and if I remove the SDA or the SCL connection, I get an error message trying `nfc-poll` which indicates that the connections are OK)

---

I have checked the position of the two switchs on the PN532 to enabled I2C communication.

---

My libnfc configuration file (`/etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`) is the following :

```
# Allow device auto-detection (default: true)
# Note: if this auto-detection is disabled, user has to set manually a device
# configuration using file or environment variable
allow_autoscan = true

# Allow intrusive auto-detection (dehttp://www.jamesrobertson.eu/pages/2014/mar/30/rfid-module.htmlfault: false)
# Warning: intrusive auto-detection can seriously disturb other devices
# This option is not recommended, user should prefer to add manually his device.
allow_intrusive_scan = false

# Set log level (default: error)
# Valid log levels are (in order of verbosity): 0 (none), 1 (error), 2 (info), 3 (debug)
# Note: if you compiled with --enable-debug option, the default log level is "debug"
log_level = 1

# Manually set default device (no default)
# To set a default device, you must set both name and connstring for your device
# Note: if autoscan is enabled, default device will be the first device available in device list.
device.name = "Itead_PN532_SPI"
device.connstring = "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
```

I have tried to set the parameter `allow_intrusive_scan` to `true`, but it do not change anything.

---

Do you have any idea ? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It sounds to me like your problem is **not** with the i2c- connection from your raspi towards your `PN532`. It would be interesting to see if you can get some status answers from it, but I'm confident you will. Depending on how the `PN532` works I'd expect some required steps to detect and read the tag you connected. 

Compacted: I guess you are currently saying 'are you there PN532'? But you need to say 'Hey PN532, is there a Tag and what is it's content?'

Comment: As I see [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/libnfc) at least nfc-poll should indeed show some data if connection is good. However- this is not exactly a hardware- board. You'd probably get better answers in places like http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

"The Raspberry Pi does not provide enough current to drive the `PN532 chip`. If you try to run the `PN532` off your `Raspberry Pi` it will reset randomly and may not respond to commands. Instead you will need `another power source (3.3v) to power the PN532`."

I found this article, it could be helpful.
https://pypi.org/project/pn532pi/

Comment: I believe this is a common source of problems, so is a legitimate answer